# How to use meteor with python numpy

Tags: meteor

Since there is no equivalent of python numpy, pandas in javascript. Is there a way to use them with meteor. numpy will do the heavy engineering and scientific computations and meteor will do everything else that is required for an engineering/scientific web application.

Is this doable or just crazy thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question!

Yes it should be possible either with the [truckload of npm modules](https://npmjs.org/) out there, one might do scientific calculation, I know theres a couple with matlab & mathematica.

If you're used to numPy you could use could too! You have to build a custom package for meteor.

There is a good example of a meteor package using a `NPM` module at : https://github.com/avital/meteor-xml2js-npm-demo.

On good example is the `python` (the npm module) : https://npmjs.org/package/python. Which lets you run python code and let node talk to it. So you could do heavy computational stuff with numPy and have meteor run it/talk to/get the results as they are changing.